# Angular material stepper header horizontal line and bottom border css

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular-material-stepper

I want to implement angular material stepper as per attached screenshot where the horizontal line has some different css on edit state and when its completed then its different.
[image]

and on edit state, there is bottom line which I need to show.

Answer (score 0):

we can get the event form selectionChange method of stepper:

```
selectionChange(event) {
    if (event.selectedIndex > 0) {
        const stepper = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-stepper-horizontal-line');
        stepper[event.selectedIndex - 1].classList.add('editState');
        for (let i = 0; i < event.previouslySelectedIndex; i++) {
            stepper[i].classList.add('completedState');
            stepper[i].classList.remove('editState');
        }
    }
}
```